# OutgoingCallReceiver (out going call) not work on some phone (Samsung, HTC ...)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I have an application that detect outgoing call with OutgoingCallReceiver class. That work on all most of the phone.

But on some phone, it doesn't event reach the function `onReceive()` of OutgoingCallReceiver class. So my app cannot detect the outgoing call. I have to reset to the factory configuration to make it work.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.*******.android.********"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="28"
    android:versionName="4.2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>        
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" /> 
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> 


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.********.android.********.********"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" > <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" > 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/AcceptCallInvisible" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".********"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.********.********.********.********.********"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" > <!-- android:launchMode="singleTop" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name=".********" />


        <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
             <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                 <meta-data />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver"
            android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
             <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that there are other apps which might be consuming this event.Try setting the proirity of the receiver to the maximum integer value..

```
 <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
             <intent-filter android:priority="100000" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                 <meta-data />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

For more info on correctly implementing it-refer http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html

You can also try changing the manifest entries.On some OEM it might give parsing errors.

Like this:

```
<uses-permission />
...
<receiver>
    <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
    <meta-data />
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've done following your advice and now i'm waiting for ours clients feed back. About what parsing errors on some OEM,  i don't think so because i have two clients with the same phone, same os (Samsung galaxy Alpha), my app work on one phone but don't work on another. I don't know what kind of popular app may consuming this event. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @KhacQuyetDang how is the client testing the app..are they doing force stop from applicaiton manager..If they are doign froce stop the receivers wont work..

Comment: @jupesh jain: i'm still waiting for their feedback.

Comment: @jupesh jain: it's not working for the client. I think that may caused by some application in conflit but i don't know which app.